# the start of fajr?

Tags: salat, sunni, prayer-timings, fajr

So there a fixed times for fajr in Muslim pro but can't we pray like 2 hours before that fixed times , as it still is practically before sunrise and after the isha prayer?

Comment: You can only pray Fajr after dawn as that is the start of its time.

Comment: Muslim Pro runs its calculations accordingly, and you can check with the local masjid.